# How to output username and ip address in bash prefix when logging into AWS EC2 with ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, aws

By default, when creating an ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance, and logging in with ssh, my bash prefix shows my username and ip address like so: `ubuntu-12.123.123.123$`. After deleting the default ubuntu user in my instance, and creating a new user, when logging in with ssh the only prefix I get is `$` in my terminal. This makes things very difficult when loggin into multiple servers at the same time, as one can easily confuse one servers terminal from the other without that prefix.

How can I get my ssh login to show the original prefix that ubuntu starts out with on EC2?

Comment: This is down to the login shell that you set for the user, and how the shell defines its prompt string (e.g. setting `PS1` inside the user's `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: How exactly do I set PS1 in ~/.bashrc?

Comment: How exactly did you create the new user? usually, you would arrange for a default set of "skeleton" configuration files to be copied from the `/etc/skel` directory - including a default `.bashrc` file with a suitable `PS1` definition.